# hibernate ogm mongo db, how to get count of collection?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

with mongo java driver for getting collection count, i use following method

```
 public Integer getUsersCount() {
        Integer listCount = 0;
        try {
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCursor cursor = mongoCoreService.getUserCollection().find(query);
            listCount = cursor.count();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listCount;
    }
```

Now I try do the same with hibernate ogm, but I cant find example or implementation.
I have entity manager

```
public int getProductCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {

        } finally {
            //em.close();
        }
         return 10;
    }
```

I tried with criteria API, but version what I use and which is work with Spring does not support criteria API. How can get collection count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following native query for getting the collection size:

```
long count = em.createNativeQuery( "db.users.count({})" ).getSingleResult();
```